# Calculating Minimal Subset With Given Sum

Tags: algorithm, scala, subset, subset-sum

I was doing a problem in Scala and this is the summary of the task statement:

> There is a list of integers (of length N, 0 < N < 10^5) and another integer S (0 < S < 10^15). You are required to find the minimal size of the minimal subset of the given list of which the sum of elements (in the subset) is greater than or equal to S.
>
> Input is given as below:
>   4
>   
> 4 12 8 10
>   4
>   4 13 30 100
>
> Output for above example:
>   
>  1
>   
>  2
>   
>  3
>   
>  -1
>
> First line is length of array, the second is the array of integers (0 < A[i] < 10^9), the third is the number of test cases (0 < T < 10^5) and the fourth contains the S (for each test case).

Here's what I tried:
The elements selected do not matter. So I sorted the list of given integers largest first. Then I selected the first one checked if its greater than S. If not, I selected the second element also, and so on until the sum becomes greater than or equal to S.

This algorithm works and I got many test cases correct. But I'm getting Time Limit Exceeded for some. If you can point out how I could make this faster or if there's a better way to do this, it would be much appreciated.

My code (Scala):

```
object Solution {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val n = readInt()
    val arr: Array[Long] = readLine().split(" ").map(_.toLong).sortWith(_ > _)

    val sums: Array[BigInt] = new Array(n)
    sums(0) = arr(0)
    for(i <- 1 until n) sums(i) = sums(i-1) + arr(i)

    val t = readInt()
    for(i <- 1 to t) {
      val s:BigInt = BigInt(readLong())
      if(sums(n-1) < s)
        println(-1)

      else {
        var i = 0
        while(sums(i) < s) i += 1
        println(i + 1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably more of the code review question, rather than stack overflow: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. One suggestion from my side would be to avoid mixing reading in the input with the algorithm itself (as this can save you some switching of the context), so first read all the inputs and then perform your algo.

Comment: @Norbert About the input, if I read the input first, then I'll have to pass through the array two times, right? And is there any way to migrate this to CodeReview? I think a moderator could do it...

Comment: A custom flag can get the attention of a moderator to migrate it (although deleting and reasking it would be easier on them), but Code Review is typically for minor improvements to code, where-as getting "Time Limit Exceeded" for a programming contest likely means that you'll need a fundamentally different approach, which won't be all that appropriate for Code Review.

Comment: @Dukeling Oh ok, then I guess I'll keep this posted on SO for a while...

Comment: Not got time to turn this into a full answer for now, but you don't need to sort the whole list. Take the first T numbers so that the sum of the T exceeds S, sort that. This is the first version of the subset. Then go through the rest of the numbers, and for each - call it X - if X exceeds the smallest in your subset, replace the lowest M, where sum of M <= X. At the end, the list will be the Z largest numbers from the list whose sum exceeds S. So your minimal subset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a full list of sums is unnecessary, and using `BigInt` is wasteful regardless--a `Long` can hold up to 9.2e18, and you are promised that only 1e15 is going to appear.  (In fact, I think 1e15 was chosen so that even a `Double` can hold the answer without loss of precision.)

Also, you can use a fast sort on primitives rather than a slow generic sort like `_ > _` which ends up boxing the integers.  So:

```
val arr = {
  val in = readLine().split(' ').map(_.toInt)
  java.util.Arrays.sort(in)
  in
}
```

Then, use an accumulator (`Long` will do):

```
var sum = 0L
```

and search for the answer with a while loop, keeping in mind that the biggest elements are last so you want to start at the end:

```
var i = arr.length-1
while (i >= 0 && sum < t) {
  sum += arr(i)
  i -= 1
}
```

Now you just need to check if you succeeded or failed before running out of elements:

```
val answer = {
  if (i < 0) -1
  else arr.length - i - 1
}
```

Comment: I think you intended `sum` to be a `var`, since you call `sum += arr(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Here it is(with O(N) memory used and O(N log N) time used)

```
scala> import math.{Ordering => Ord}
import math.{Ordering=>Ord}

scala> def search(src: Seq[Long], dst: Seq[Long]): Seq[Int] = {
     |   val cum = src.sorted(Ord.Long.reverse).scanLeft(0L)(_ + _)
     |   dst.map{ v => cum.indexWhere(x => x >= v) }
     | }
search: (src: Seq[Long], dst: Seq[Long])Seq[Int]

scala> search(Seq(4, 12, 8, 10), Seq(4, 13, 30, 100))
res6: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, -1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm having trouble mapping the input I read from stdin (one per line, for the test cases (T)) into a passable Seq. Care to help me a bit? :) Sorry I'm a Scala newbie...