# Get sum of combinations of array values in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming

I know that there have been a few similar questions to this but there still doesn't seem to be a definitive answer to this so I will ask it..

I have an `array` of values and am trying to find the correct values that will sum to a `limit` value or the closest it can get (without exceeding it) from any given combination.

Using this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168934/calculating-minimal-subset-with-given-sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168934/calculating-minimal-subset-with-given-sum#23171899) I have this:

```
    def getLimitArr(arr: Array[Int], limit: Int): Unit = {

       scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(arr) // Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 34)
       var sum = 0L
       var i = arr.length-1

       val arr2 = ArrayBuffer[Integer]()
       while (i >= 0 && sum < limit) {
         if(sum + arr(i)<=limit) {
            sum += arr(i)
            arr2 += arr(i)
         }
         i -= 1 // 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
       }

    println(arr2.mkString(", ") + " = " + sum)

   }
```

And calling it using this in the main method:

```
   val arr = Array(3, 34, 4, 11, 5, 2)
   getLimitArr(arr, 9)
```

Which returns:

```
   println(arr2.mkString(", ") + " = " + sum) // 5, 4 = 9
```

This is good but only if the values (that make up the sum) can be made from the highest value that is lower than the limit; in this example 5 - which works with this array as we can see. But if the limit value was 12 (`getLimitArr(arr, 12)`) with this array then it would return `11 = 11` rather than using `5 + 4 + 3`.

I have done this using ***subsets*** but when the array is more than 10 I get the ***memory heap error*** as it is formulating all of the combinations before being able to obtain the answer.

So how would we do this by being memory efficient, using the current format or taking advantage of Scala's functional programming capabilities?

Comment: this seems like a variation of the knapsack problem, with a known solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: It looks to be but that doesn't answer the question of how to code an efficient solution using many array values and not causing a **memory heap error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion is often useful when we want to terminate as soon as the first correct answer is found.

```
def getLimit(nums: Array[Int], limit: Int): Array[Int] = {
  val subset = nums.filter(limit.>=)
  if (subset.isEmpty) Array()
  else (1 to subset.length).flatMap(subset.combinations)
                           .find(_.sum == limit)
                           .fold(getLimit(subset, limit-1))(identity)
}

getLimit(Array(3, 34, 4, 11, 5, 2), 5)   // res0: Array[Int] = Array(5)
getLimit(Array(3, 34, 4, 11, 5, 2), 9)   // res1: Array[Int] = Array(4, 5)
getLimit(Array(3, 34, 4, 11, 5, 2), 12)  // res2: Array[Int] = Array(3, 4, 5)
getLimit(Array(3, 34, 4, 11, 5, 2), 24)  // res3: Array[Int] = Array(3, 4, 11, 5)
```

Note that the last one sums to 23 because there is no combination that sums to 24.

**update**

A better shortcut added and the method is now tail recursive.

```
def getLimit(nums: Array[Int], limit: Int): Array[Int] = {
  val subset = nums.filter(limit.>=)
  if (subset.sum <= limit) subset
  else {
    val res = (1 to subset.length).view
                                  .flatMap(subset.combinations)
                                  .find(_.sum == limit)
    if (res.isEmpty) getLimit(subset, limit-1)
    else res.get
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but with any more than several array values; if the solution isn't found just using one or two we get the **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded** error. I'm looking for something that can handle up to 30 array values_

Comment: It's definitely better and it is a worthy answer but it can't handle 30 array values and I can't help but feel that there is a leaner solution that can

Comment: Just to say that although it doesn't handle up to 30 in an array I think it could be the best option so marked it as correct. Of course if anyone has anything to add then that would be useful to others out there. Thanks